# Embed Into UIScrollview and keep contraints

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, ios8, autolayout, embed

I have an layout that I just finished designing but now I am finding out that it needs to be inside of a scrollview in order for a function to work(making sure the keyboard doesn't hide the field) Is there a way I can embed a view into a scrollview while keeping the constraints. Whenever I select the option all the constraints are deleted. I spent days trying to get it to work properly and i'd hate to have to this all over again.

Comment: Copy and paste it into itself THEN do the UIScrollView